# how can upgrade my Ubuntu LTS to new version which is also LTS without any changes in my current os?

Tags: upgrade

I want to install a new version of Ubuntu without deleting my old apps and without changing my system settings. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading means that some *system* programs will be added, some deleted, and other upgraded to newer versions. These changes may or may not break other software that you have installed. During upgrade you may see some options to keep old configuration or upgrade to package maintainer versions. If you choose to keep the old configurations, just make sure they're compatible with the newer versions of the software being upgraded.

If you have installed applications from outside the repositories and these applications rely on dependencies (installed from the repos) of a particular version, you may have issues with those applications.

**Doing the upgrade:**

- Before trying anything, you should [**backup your entire system!**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem)  I personally like to use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).
- Once you have a system image of your current setup, try the upgrade.
- If it succeeds, great!
- If it breaks something you need, revert back by restoring from the system image you took before attempting the upgrade.